# evaluate the integral of two variables using a previous integral of complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate  $\int \frac{(x+1)dx+y dy}{(x+1)^2+y^2}$ along the circle |z|=2. i replaced $x+1$ by $R$ $cos t$ and $y$ by $R$ $sint$ , hence i got that the value of the integral is $0$. However, the question wants to use the fact that $\int \frac{dz}{z+1}=2\pi i$to evaluate the previous integral, how can i use this fact?

Comment: Is this an integral along some contour?

Comment: Yes it is along the circle |z|=2

Comment: $$\Re\int\frac{dz}{z+1}=\Re\int\frac{(\bar z+1)dz}{|z+1|^2}=\Re\int\frac{(x+1-iy)(dx+idy)}{(x+1)^2+y^2}=\cdots$$